# How can I prefetch nested tables?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an app with a DRF API. Development has been going on for some months, but only now are we running into performance issues when populating the database with actual data. I have done some profiling and found out that many endpoints query the database hundreds of times to fetch the necessary data. This is something that can be solved with `select_related` and `prefetch_related`, that much I know, but I'm having a hard time picturing it.

**Models**

```py
class LegalFile(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contactrole = models.ManyToManyField(LegalFileContactRole, blank=True, related_name='contactroles')

class LegalFileContactRole(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, related_name='legal_file_contact')
    subtype = models.ForeignKey(ContactSubType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='legal_file_contact_role', null=True)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    surname_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    surname_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)

class ContactSubType(models.Model):
    pass
```

Say I want to list all the `LegalFiles` in the database, and fetch the names and both surnames of the contacts associated to each `LegalFile` through `LegalFileContactRole`. Is there a DRYer way than using lowercase notation to prefetch like `LegalFile.prefetch_related('contactrole__contact__name', 'contactrole__contact__surname_1', 'contactrole__contact__surname_2')`? This kind of nested relationship is a recurring thing in the app.

### Editing in response to Marc Compte's comment:

I have not explained myself properly, I think. In fact, this is missing a good chunk of context - I have not mentioned serializers at all, for instance.

I have taken the approach described in [this post](https://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/) and created a method to set eager loading up:

```py
class LegalFileReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contactrole = LegalFileContactRoleSerializer(many=True)
    
    @classmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(cls, queryset):
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('contactrole__contact__name', 'contactrole__contact__surname_1', 'contactrole__contact__surname_2')
        return queryset
    class Meta:
        model = LegalFile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('__all__',)

class LegalFileViewSet(CustomViewSet):
    model = models.LegalFile
    read_serializer_class = serializers.LegalFileReadSerializer
    write_serializer_class = serializers.LegalFileWriteSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(queryset)
        return queryset
```

(Note this is still work in progress and will have to be decoupled further for reuse, in a mixin or something)

Could I, so to speak, chain serializers? Like:

```py
class LegalFileReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contactrole = LegalFileContactRoleSerializer(many=True)
    
    @classmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(cls, queryset):
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('contactrole',)
        return queryset
    class Meta:
        model = LegalFile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('__all__',)

class LegalFileContactRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = ContactReadSerializer()
    subtype = ContactSubTypeReadSerializer()
    @classmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(cls, queryset):
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('contact',)
        return queryset
    class Meta:
        model = models.LegalFileContactRole
        fields = '__all__'

class ContactReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # And so on
    pass
```

This, in my head at least, makes sense, but I don't know if this behavior is possible or even advisable. It seems that if I chain serializers like this (implying again that it's possible to do so) I'm gonna run into problems picking up too much unneeded information.

Comment: If, by DRYer you mean not repeating the string 'contactrole_contact', I'm not sure. You could use select_related to make Django do INNER JOINS instead of multiple queries and you'd only need to specify the fk fields in the main model. But if you want to limit the selected fields in each of the related models, you also have to "repeat" that string when selecting the fields. I'm sure you can find a way, but I'm not sure I'd use it if it is not easy to read. DRY is good, but not necessarily always, IMHO.

Comment: You don't specify the fields in the prefetch related call, you specify the _model_ hence you need to call `.prefetch_related('contactrole__contact')`